# Combine equivalent items in a list

Tags: haskell

Let's say I have the following type

```
type Key = String
type Score = Int
data Thing = Thing Key Score
```

And if I have an array of them like this:

```
[Thing "a" 7, Thing "b" 5, Thing "a" 10]
```

Is there a standard way to reduce this so that I don't have any duplicate keys? If two keys match, I want to take the better score

```
[Thing "b" 5, Thing "a" 10]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically first we must decide what is problem solving and what is implementation difficulties. So what If we first sort by `Score`, and then just keep the first occurrences in the sorted list with respect to `Key`? That should work, let's look at the haskell implementation:

```
import Data.List
import Data.Function

type Key = String
type Score = Int
data Thing = Thing { key :: Key, score :: Score }
  deriving (Show)

myNub  = nubBy  ((==) `on` key)
mySort = sortBy (compare `on` (negate . score))

selectFinest = myNub . mySort
```

Now we try run this in `ghci`:

```
Prelude> :load Test.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Test.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
*Main> selectFinest [Thing "a" 7, Thing "b" 5, Thing "a" 10]
[Thing {key = "a", score = 10},Thing {key = "b", score = 5}]
```

Checkout [hoogle](http://haskell.org/hoogle/) if you are uncertain about the functions I used in the solution. It indeed takes some time to learn how to use `on` and those functions.

Answer (score 6):

A very simple solution is to use [`Data.Map.fromListWith`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/Data-Map.html#v%3afromListWith), which converts a list of key-value pairs to a map, given a function to combine multiple values with the same key.

```
Prelude Data.Map> fromListWith max [("a", 7), ("b", 5), ("a", 10)]
fromList [("a",10),("b",5)]
```

Note that this expects tuples, so convert as necessary. Also, it does not preserve the order of the input elements. Run time is O(n log n).

Comment: +1. Excellent solution! It was quite counter-intuitive, as you actually sort by the keys (unlike my solution), however `max`  will let only the greatest of values remain.

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting a O(n log n) solution, since everyone seems fine with being O(n^2)

```
consolidate :: (Ord a, Ord b) => [Thing a b] -> [Thing a b]
consolidate xs = 
    max_from_each_group (sortBy (compare `on` getKey) xs)
    where
       max_from_each_group [] = []
       max_from_each_group (x:xs) = 
           let (same_key, rest) = span (\t -> x == getKey t) xs in
           let group_max = maximumBy (compare `on` getValue) (x:same_key) in
           group_max : max_from_each_group rest
```

Comment: `max_from_each_group (sortBy (compare `on` getKey))` looks like a type error to me

Comment: @PhilipJF: What? I don't see anything ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my feeble attempt. There surely is a nicer way but I'm not
much of a Haskell programmer.

```
import Data.List

type Key = String
type Score = Int
data Thing = Thing Key Score
           deriving (Show, Ord)

instance Eq Thing where
    (Thing k1 _) == (Thing k2 _) = k1 == k2
    (Thing k1 _) /= (Thing k2 _) = k1 /= k2

thingSort :: [Thing] -> [Thing]
thingSort = Data.List.sortBy (flip compare)

ex = [Thing "a" 7, Thing "b" 5, Thing "a" 10]

filtered = nub (thingSort ex)
```